# jQuery Mobile AJAX Loading Previous DATA with Search Results

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am currently working on a mobile app, and using jQuery Mobile. This app is basically a search engine for products.

Currently, if I were to search for a product, my script processes what is submitted in the search field, and finds any related products. The results come from a JSON file loaded via AJAX. This works without flaw.

The problem I am having, is that if I were to search for "one", and then go back to the search field to search again. Once I search for something else. The results from the first search are still on the results page, along with my new search results. This is obviously a problem.

How do I clear the AJAX data once the apps "back" button has been clicked? That way, if I search for "one", then go back and search for "two". I only see the results from my most recent search.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to give us more info, this is not enough. When you submit search are your data loaded into a listview and click on a listview forwards to to an another page or what? This part is necessary for a correct answer.

Comment: Yes, if you search for "one", you get the results for "one" in a listview on the results page. If you click one of the results, it then takes you to a details page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you return to the previous page you need to take a look if listview content is empty, if this is not a case them empty it.

I made you a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/bTgth/, lets say when you open this example it acts like your page back action.

When page with an id index opens, we will check if list has a content, if this is true empty it:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
    if($('#custom-list li').length > 0){
        $('#custom-list').empty();
    }
});
```